# How to add onclick action on rect that changes colour for selected tab?

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I need to add action onclick will change it colour (to gray). And then it will stay gray until it will be clicked to another tab.

I want  to show tab in selected state (by having gray colour). If you click on another tab it color changes to gray and previously click tab color change to white.

This is part of my code:
[image]

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo-print.css" type="text/css" media="print">
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #canvas {
                height: 300px;
                left: 50%;
                margin: -150px 0 0 -300px;
                position: absolute;
                top: 50%;
                width: 600px;
            }
            #paper {
                height: 300px;
                left: 0;
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                width: 300px;
            }
            #nsw, #vic, #wa, #sa, #nt, #qld, #tas {
                display: none;
                height: 400px;
                overflow: auto;
                position: absolute;
                right: 0;
                top: 0;
                width: 300px;
            }
            h2 {
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
        <script src="raphael.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        window.onload = function () {
            var R = Raphael("paper", 700, 700);
            var attr = {
                fill: "#333",
                stroke: "#666",
                "stroke-width": 1,
                "stroke-linejoin": "round"
            };
            var aus = {};
            var outsideRectX1=30, outsideRectY1=30,outsideRectX2=220, outsideRectY2=480, outsideRectR=10;
            aus.nsw = R.rect(outsideRectX1+40, outsideRectY1+70, 120, 40,0);
            aus.vic = R.rect(outsideRectX1+160, outsideRectY1+70, 120, 40,0);
            aus.wa = R.rect(outsideRectX1+280, outsideRectY1+70, 120, 40,0);
            aus.sa = R.rect(outsideRectX1+400, outsideRectY1+70, 120, 40,0);

            var text3=R.text(outsideRectX1+75, outsideRectY1+85,"tab1").attr({fill: '#000000', 'font-family':'Vardana', 'font-size':'14px', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
var text4=R.text(outsideRectX1+195, outsideRectY1+85,"tab2").attr({fill: '#000000', 'font-family':'Vardana', 'font-size':'14px', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
var text5=R.text(outsideRectX1+315, outsideRectY1+85,"tab3").attr({fill: '#000000', 'font-family':'Vardana', 'font-size':'14px', 'font-weight': 'bold'});
var text6=R.text(outsideRectX1+435, outsideRectY1+85,"tab4").attr({fill: '#000000', 'font-family':'Vardana', 'font-size':'14px', 'font-weight': 'bold'});

            var current = null;
            for (var state in aus) {
                aus[state].color = Raphael.getColor();
                (function (st, state) {
                    st[0].style.cursor = "pointer";
                    st[0].click = function () {
                        current && aus[current].animate({fill: "#333", stroke: "#666"}, 500) && (document.getElementById(current).style.display = "");
                        st.animate({fill: st.color, stroke: "#ccc"}, 500);
                        st.toFront();
                        R.safari();
                        document.getElementById(state).style.display = "block";
                        current = state;
                    };

                })(aus[state], state);
            }
        };

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="canvas">
            <div id="paper"></div>
            <div id="nsw"> </div>
            <div id="vic">  </div>
            <div id="wa"></div>
            <div id="sa">             

        </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a distilled version of your code, I have removed the irrelevant parts to simplify the work:

```
var R = Raphael("paper", 700, 700);
var aus = {};
aus.nsw = R.set()
aus.vic = R.set()
aus.wa = R.set()
aus.sa = R.set()
var boxattrs = {'cursor': 'pointer', 'fill' : "#fff"}
var attrs = {fill: '#000000', 'font-family':'Verdana', 'font-size':'14px', 'font-weight': 'bold', 'cursor': 'pointer'}
var outsideRectX1=30.5, outsideRectY1=30.5,outsideRectX2=220.5, outsideRectY2=480.5, outsideRectR=10.5;
var i = 0;

for (state in aus) {
  aus[state].push(R.rect((outsideRectX1+90)*i+80, outsideRectY1+70, 120, 40,0).attr(boxattrs));
  aus[state].push(R.text((outsideRectX1+90)*i+115, outsideRectY1+85,"tab" + (i+1)).attr(attrs));
  aus[state].click(highlight)
  i++;
}

function highlight() {
   for (state in aus) {
     if(aus[state][0].attr("fill") == "#CCCCCC") {
       aus[state][0].animate({fill: "#FFFFFF", "stroke": "#000"}, 300)
     }
   }
   node = (this.type == "rect") ? this : this.prev
   node.animate({fill: "#CCCCCC", "stroke": "#CCC"}, 300)
}
```

You can view it live here http://jsfiddle.net/xYfXE/